How to rotate a function (or change axis) in Tikz-3Dplots
I would like to know how to either rotate y = sqrt(1-x^2) about the x axis or draw an arc in the x-z plane that will essentially do the same thing. The ability to rotate would be preferable for future projects.
I am essentially trying to show how to calculate the volume by splicing.
TIA
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{130}{60}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3, tdplot_main_coords,font=\footnotesize]
\coordinate (A) at (-0.75,0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (-0.75,{sqrt(0.4375)},0);
\coordinate (C) at (-0.75,0,{sqrt(0.4375)});
\draw[thick,<->] (-1.2,0,0) -- (1.2,0,0) node[anchor=south west]{$x$};
\draw[thick,<->] (0,-0.5,0) -- (0,1.2,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1.2) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
\tdplotsetcoord{P}{1}{30}{60}
\draw [domain=-1:1,samples=100] plot (\x,{(1-\x*\x)^0.5}) node [shift={(0,3,0)}] {$y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$};
\draw [dashed,fill=green!20] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


The parametric formulas for the sphere are: \newcommand{\sphereX}[2]{cos(#2)*cos(#1)} \newcommand{\sphereY}[2]{cos(#2)*sin(#1)} \newcommand{\sphereZ}[2]{sin(#2)}

Achieving a x-axis rotation just involves using the dot product, let me write you an answer. Nevermind, it actually is easier than that.

The key for a x-axis rotation is to use ZYZ rotations, and (possibly, but not in this case) the dot product. Here we just align the y-axis with the x-axis, then we rotate about the y-axis as though it were the x-axis, then we rotate about the new z-axis to orient the shape properly.
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{130}{60}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\draw[thick,<->] (-2,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[anchor=south west]{$x$};
\draw[thick,<->] (0,-2,0) -- (0,2,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,-2) -- (0,0,2) node[anchor=south]{$z$};

\foreach \angle in {10,20,...,60}{
    \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{-90}{\angle}{90}
    \begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
        \draw [domain=-1:1,samples=100] plot (\x,{(1-\x*\x)^0.5});
    \end{scope}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



I would recommend the  parametric sphere formulas though.

Thanks, this works.
